# Copying only files in subfolders to destination

Tags: c#

I have a folder structure as below:

```
C:\test\test1.dll
C:\test\subtest\test2.dll
C:\test\subtest\test3.dll
C:\test\supertest\test4.dll
```

I want to copy only the assemblies (.dlls) but not the sub folders to destination C:\dest*.dll (i.e; My folder dest should contain test1.dll, test2.dll, test3.dll and test4.dll). How could I go on this????

Comment: Googled but I could only see copying of files with respect to directories and subdirectories but not all dlls at a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I am misunderstanding your question, but you could use

[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) with search option [AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx) and filter "*.dll"

You could try something like

```
List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
files.ForEach(f => File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(@"C:\dest", Path.GetFileName(f))));
```

You would have to ensure that the destination directory exists before coping. Also, if the files already exist in the destination directory, you will have an exception thrown.

Comment: this is what i am looking for. Im not a developer so maybe i am not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using the FOR command. Something like this:

```
for /r %f in (*.dll) do copy %~nxf c:\dest
```

`/r` walks the tree.
`~nx` reconstructs the file name with no path.